# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException Error in for loop

Tags: java, android, android-studio

when i build my project no error appears but when the application start it crashed and give me that error in line 97  in the for loop [ for (User user1 : mUsers)  ]
the error is: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.chatapp, PID: 9908
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

i didn't understand that error and why this error appears.

here is my code:

```
private UserAdapter userAdapter;
private List<User> mUsers;
FirebaseUser fuser;
DatabaseReference reference;
private List<String>usersList;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false);

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycle_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    fuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    usersList = new ArrayList<>();

    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chat");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            usersList.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Chat chat = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);

                assert chat != null;
                if (chat.getSender().equals(fuser.getUid())){
                    usersList.add(chat.getReceiver());
                }
                if (chat.getReceiver().equals(fuser.getUid())){
                    usersList.add(chat.getSender());
                }
            }
            readChats();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

    return view;
}

public void readChats(){
    mUsers = new ArrayList<>();
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mUsers.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                // display user from chats
                for (String id : usersList){

                    if (user.getId().equals(id)){
                        if (mUsers.size() != 0){
                            for (User user1 : mUsers){   // error here
                                if (!user.getId().equals(user1.getId())){
                                    mUsers.add(user);
                                }
                            }
                        }else {
                            mUsers.add(user);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            userAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(), mUsers);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here :

```
for (User user1 : mUsers){   // error here
        if (!user.getId().equals(user1.getId())){
            mUsers.add(user);
        }
}
```

You add an element in the collection while you iterate on that with an Iterator.  That is not allowed.
Note that the `enhanced for` loop that you use `for (User user1 : mUsers)` after compilation is expressed as an [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Iterator.html).

To overcome that limitation you could use a [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ListIterator.html) that is (emphasis is mine) :

> An iterator for lists that allows the programmer **to traverse the list**
> in either direction, **modify the list during iteration**, and obtain the
> iterator's current position in the list.

```
ListIterator<User> listIteratorUser = mUsers.listIterator();
while(listIteratorUser.hasNext()){   
      User user1 = listIteratorUser.next();
      if (!user.getId().equals(user1.getId())){
          listIteratorUser.add(user);
      }
  }
```

Comment: great, that works thank you :)